# High School Calculus. If $y=x^2$ then why is $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$

Tags: calculus

My Math teacher told me that  $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$. I asked for a proof and he gave me the result by using the chain rule. I don't understand why this is the case for every function because the function $y=x^2$ doesn't have an inverse function.  If this is the case then why is $\frac{dx}{dy}$ not $\frac{-1}{2x}$? Maybe it only works for injective functions or we assume only one of the values to be true.

Comment: $x=y^{1/2}$ is a valid inverse for $x$, $y>0$. Then $dx/dy=(1/2)y^{-1/2}$. Does that make sense?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Isn't $x=-y^{1/2}$ a valid inverse too? Why do we only consider the positive one?

Comment: What you have to do is consider this as an equation that holds (or doesn't hold) at various points $(a,b)$ in the plane, specifically those points such that $b = a^2.$ At each such point, you identify what $\frac{dx}{dy}$ is and what $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is, and check that the identity holds at that point. What you have to watch out for is that "a formula for $a$ in terms of $b$" is different when $a \geq 0$ as compared to when $a \leq 0,$ similar to the way in which $|x| = x$ when $x \geq 0$ and $|x| = -x$ when $x \leq 0.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Lets say I find $\frac {dy}{dx}$ at $x = 2$. I get 4. Now I evaluate $\frac {dx}{dy}$ at $y=4$. Now I get two values, $+0.25$ and $-0.25$. Only one of the values is the same as the one we get when we take the inverse of $\frac {dy}{dx}$. Why do we take the first one as correct. Seems to me that we are ignoring the second one for the sake of making $\frac {dy}{dx} = \frac {1}{\frac {dx}{dy}}$ true.

Comment: "*Now I get two values*" --- Note that I said you have to consider points $(a,b)$ (both coordinates specified). The usual short-cut of having to only specify the $x$-coordinate doesn't necessarily work when there is more than one point on the graph having that same $x$-coordinate, and it definitely doesn't work when the graph's "local direction" differs at these different points (corresponding to the same $x$-coordinate).

Comment: [This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bk9IKHS5KbY) seems to be relevant to what you're asking about. I haven't watched it, but a quick spot-check of various places in it suggests that in the first 8 minutes it goes through one of the standard examples for illustrating the inverse function theorem.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro So instead of evaluating the derivative at $x=2$ we need to specify that it is at $x=2$ and $y=4$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you need to specify the actual point (both coordinates) in the plane. This probably would not have been as troublesome if functions were not held in such high regard, but there are reasons for this . . .

Answer (score 1):

There is such a thing as a function being **locally** one-to-one, and you frequently, at least tacitly, rely on that idea in many of the implicit differentiation problems that get assigned in first-semester calculus.

To say that $f$ is locally one-to-one at a point $a$ in the domain of $f$ means that there is some open interval, say $(a-\varepsilon,a+\varepsilon)$ within the domain of $f,$ for which the restriction of $f$ to that interval is one-to-one. The formula you give applies to such restrictions. Since derivatives are an inherently local idea, this is not problematic.

Notice that in implicit differentiation problems they give you something like $x^2 + 3y^2 = 1,$ and expect you to deduce that $2x+ 6y\dfrac{dy}{dx} =0,$ even though the equation does that implicitly defines $y$ as a function of $x$ does not have a unique solution for $x.$ You're just applying differentiation in a small neighborhood of each point on the curve.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Let's avoid Leibniz notation. In Lagrange notation, the [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem) for a differentiable function $f\colon\R\to\R$ states that when $f(a)=b$ then
$$
g'(b) = \frac 1{f'(a)},
$$
where $g$ is a *local inverse* of $f$ at $a$. This means, that $g$ is a function $g\colon U\to V$, where $U$ is an open set containing $f(a)$, $V$ is an open set containing $a$ and we have
\begin{align*}
f(g(y)) &= y \quad\text{for all $y\in U$}, \\
g(f(x)) &= x \quad\text{for all $x\in V$}.
\end{align*}

Let's apply this to $f(x) = x^2$ with derivative $f'(x)=2x$. For $x=2$ we have $f(x)=4$ and we can pick the local inverse $g_1\colon \R_{>0}\to\R_{>0}, y\mapsto \sqrt y$. We see that $g_1'(y) = \frac 1{2\sqrt{y}}$ and can verify
$$
g_1'(4) = \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{f'(2)}.
$$
For $x=-2$, we can not pick the same $g_1$ as a local inverse, since $-2$ is not even contained in $V=\R_{>0}$ and there is no hope in making $V$ bigger since we would get
$$
g_1(f(-2)) = g_1(4) = 2 \neq -2.
$$
But we can instead pick $g_2\colon \R_{>0}\to\R_{<0}, y\mapsto -\sqrt{y}$ to get a correct local inverse and again verify the inverse function theorem:
$$
g_2'(4) = -\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{f'(-2)}.
$$

Comment: Just in case you didn't realise, the OP is a high school student learning what seems to be the very first chapter of calculus...

Comment: So we should not offer a rigorous treatment of the mathematics involved? When I was a high school student I was usually frustrated by stuff like this not being clearly defined. You shouldn't teach "$\mathrm dx/\mathrm dy = 1/(\mathrm dy/\mathrm dx)$" without mentioning local invertibility IMHO.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your principle. In fact, I share the same sentiment. But writing in an appropriate language and terms for a particular audience is another issue altogether.

Comment: Good thing that this is not the only answer given then ;-) A student interested in learning the details has all the possibilities to look up the unknown terms in my answer. I can't define everything in the answer but wanted to at least mention what is involved so the reader knows where to look further.

Answer (score 0):

If $y=x^2$ then $$\frac{dy}{dx}=2x$$
and $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is given by using implicity derivative w.r.t $y$:

$$1=2x\frac{dx}{dy}\to \frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{2x}$$

Comment: You're using the chain rule which is part of the question. My main question is that why does the chain rule hold for non-injective functions.

Comment: @Arjun Nigam: use the definition of derivative. Use limit.

Answer (score 0):

The branch choice doesn't matter, since if $x=-y^{1/2}$ then $\frac{dx}{dy}=-\frac{1}{2}y^{-1/2}=\frac{1}{2x}$. A general proof that $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$ is easy if you write each side as a limit by definition.

Comment: Starting from $y=x^2$, you seem to be using $\sqrt{y} = -x$ here, which is only true for $x\le 0$. The branch choice does matter.

Comment: @Christoph I'm not using the branch choice; I'm merely pointing out you get $\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{1}{2x}$ for any sign in $x=\pm y^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

The formula ${dx\over dy}={1\over dy/dx}$ as a general principle does not refer to a global situation, but to a window $W$ in the $(x,y)$-plane, centered at some point $(x_0,y_0)$, within which the "variables" $x$ and $y$ are dependent on each other in such a way that you can write $y=\phi(x)$, whereby  $\phi(x_0)=y_0$, as well as $x=\psi(y)$, whereby $\psi(y_0)=x_0$. Assume that the points $(x,y)\in W$ satisfying $y=\phi(x)$, resp., $x=\psi(y)$ are lying on a curve $\gamma$ through the point $(x_0,y_0)$ whose tangent $t_0$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ is neither vertical nor horizontal. Inspecting a figure showing the window $W$ you can convince yourself that the slope of $t_0$  when viewed with respect to the $x$-axis, i.e., as tangent to $y=\phi(x)$, is $\phi'(x_0)$, and  when viewed with respect to the $y$-axis, i.e., as tangent to $x=\psi(y)$ is $\psi'(y_0)$. It follows that $\psi'(y_0)={1\over\phi'(x_0)}$.